# ETL - determine deleted entries - Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, etl

I am summarizing my use case in a basic form as below. Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

ETL:

```
                      |-> FINAL DB 
SOURCE -> INTERIM DB -|
                      |-> HISTORY DB
```

1. HISTORY DB is updated with the diff in entries between INTERIM and FINAL DB.
2. FINAL DB is updated using Merge utility of Oracle.
3. On Day 1, we extract data from SOURCE and put 10 entries in INTERIM DB.
4. We run a PL/SQL flow which updates FINAL DB and HISTORY DB each with 10 entries.
5. On Day2, another 10 entries come. But 1 is update, 1 is delete, 1 is insert.
6. So now, FINAL DB has total 11 entires (earlier 10 + 1 insert) and HISTORY DB has 13 entries(all inserts (earlier 10 + 1 update + 1 delete + 1 insert)).
7. We use the entries in HISTORY DB with DELETE statuses to delete entries in FINAL DB.
8. The above premise holds true if we are pulling all the entries from SOURCE.
9. If we pull only the delta data (the entries that changed), then it gives incorrect deletes. For ex: instead of fetching all 10 (like in step (5)), if I fetch only 2 entries (1 update and 1 insert), there is no way to find DELETES in HISTORY table (as the remaining 8 entries that are not fetched, will also be marked as DELETE in HISTORY table).

**Question:**
The real scenario involves millions of records and hence we cannot fetch all the data in INTERIM DB. Oracle `Merge` statement merges the changes into FINAL DB but doesn't do the deletes which we plan to do it by running additional delete statements using the entries in history table having status as 'DELETE'. But the question is how can we have the correct entries in history table, when we have delta data in INTERIM DB?

**One solution:**
To Fetch full data periodically, to determine the deletes.

Please suggest any other solutions/thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you have hand-rolled a replication mechanism instead of using one of Oracle's built-in methods: replication with Materialized Views, Oracle Streams, CDC or GoldenGate (depending on database version, edition and/or depth of pockets).

Comment: Thanks for your response and edits. Any other thoughts/solutions on the above issue will be appreciated.

Comment: agree with above comment about hand rolling this, however if you are going to go ahead with it, my solution would be to implement a delete trigger on all your source DB tables, populating a temporary table with the ID of the deleted record and table it was deleted from.  This will allow you to just pull the deletes from this table rather than trying to pull full dataset.

Comment: Thanks Shaun for responding. Yes, that can be a possible solution but that would involve changing all the sources which may or may not be in our control. Will check further though.